# List of figures modification

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

List of figures organize all the figures as the following.

```
2.1 Caption for 2.1. . . . . . . . .  6  
2.2 Caption for 2.2. . . . . . . . .  7  
2.3 Caption for 2.3. . . . . . . . . 11
```

and so on. For my dissertation, I need to do

```
Figure 2.1 Caption for 2.1. . . . . . . . .  6  
Figure 2.2 Caption for 2.2. . . . . . . . .  7  
Figure 2.3 Caption for 2.3. . . . . . . . . 11
```

and so on. I tried to accomplish this by including the following in my preamble.

```
\titlecontents{figure}[6.2em]{}{%
\makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace*{-6.2em}\rm Figure \thecontentslabel:\enspace}}%
{}{\titlerule*[0.75pc]{.} \contentspage}
```

This was working nicely, until I had too many figures. Now the list of figures breaks the bottom margin and does not go on the second page.

Could I modify the code I have above to make this behave in the way it should? If not, could I accomplish my goal in a different way?

Edit: I quickly created an example below. It doesn't have actual figures, but it illustrates the problem I have.

```
\documentclass[paper=letter, fontsize=11pt, chapterprefix=on, oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\linespread{1.3}

\titlecontents{figure}[6.2em]{}{%
\makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace*{-6.2em}\rm Figure \thecontentslabel:\enspace}}%
{}{\titlerule*[0.75pc]{.} \contentspage}
%\addtocontents{lof}{\linespread{1.5}\selectfont}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\newpage
\begin{figure}\caption{Caption for figure 0.1}\label{fig:0.1}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{Caption for figure 0.2}\label{fig:0.2}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{Caption for figure 0.3}\label{fig:0.3}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{Caption for figure 0.4}\label{fig:0.4}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{Caption for figure 0.5}\label{fig:0.5}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{Caption for figure 0.6}\label{fig:0.6}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{Caption for figure 0.7}\label{fig:0.7}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{Caption for figure 0.8}\label{fig:0.8}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{Caption for figure 0.9}\label{fig:0.9}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{Caption for figure 0.10}\label{fig:0.10}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{Caption for figure 0.11}\label{fig:0.11}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{Caption for figure 0.12}\label{fig:0.12}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{Caption for figure 0.13}\label{fig:0.13}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{Caption for figure 0.14}\label{fig:0.14}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{Caption for figure 0.15}\label{fig:0.15}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{Caption for figure 0.16}\label{fig:0.16}\end{figure}
\clearpage
\begin{figure}\caption{Caption for figure 0.17}\label{fig:0.17}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{Caption for figure 0.18}\label{fig:0.18}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{Caption for figure 0.19}\label{fig:0.19}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{Caption for figure 0.20}\label{fig:0.20}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{Caption for figure 0.21}\label{fig:0.21}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{Caption for figure 0.22}\label{fig:0.22}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{Caption for figure 0.23}\label{fig:0.23}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{Caption for figure 0.24}\label{fig:0.24}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{Caption for figure 0.25}\label{fig:0.25}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{Caption for figure 0.26}\label{fig:0.26}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{Caption for figure 0.27}\label{fig:0.27}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{Caption for figure 0.28}\label{fig:0.28}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{Caption for figure 0.29}\label{fig:0.29}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{Caption for figure 0.30}\label{fig:0.30}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{Caption for figure 0.31}\label{fig:0.31}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{Caption for figure 0.32}\label{fig:0.32}\end{figure}
\clearpage
\begin{figure}\caption{Caption for figure 0.33}\label{fig:0.33}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{Caption for figure 0.34}\label{fig:0.34}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{Caption for figure 0.35}\label{fig:0.35}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{Caption for figure 0.36}\label{fig:0.36}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{Caption for figure 0.37}\label{fig:0.37}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{Caption for figure 0.38}\label{fig:0.38}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{Caption for figure 0.39}\label{fig:0.39}\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: We need a minimal working example, I just try and there is no problem.

Comment: if you delete `tocloft` it will be okay. do you realy need it?

Comment: In my main document, yes, I do need it. If I comment it out, it does not compile the pdf file.

Comment: in this case may be better to use `\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{\makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace*{-6.2em}\rm Figure}}` from `tocloft` rather than `\titelcontents`

Comment: I don't recommande `\rm`

Comment: Thanks a bunch, touhami. However, something is conflicting in the preamble of my main document. It does not work. This format editing has been a pain, and I just can't figure out an easy way to do this.